# when ever i move/pose a bone blender lags/freezes

Tags: animation, bones

when ever I move a bone in pose mode my blender freezes/does not respond for 10s and then moves the bone and the mesh

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is either very complicated, you have a bad PC, or both. I suggest disabling or lowering the quality of subdivision modifiers in the viewport if you have them on the mesh, or upgrading your PC

Comment: BRO THANKS  u saved my soul and my life with that my blender model is fine now after i removed subsurface